# Insert values with all existent possible values

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, sql-insert, insert-update

I have a question that I do not know if it's possible. I have a database with some permissions to our system. The system is separated with routines named as numbers (routine 3735, 3734 for example) and it have lots of routines, there are about 100+ routines. The table has this values: usrcod, routcod, access? (S or N), ex:

```
select * from pccontro
```

returns

```
user    rout    access?
39528   3717    N
39528   3734    S
39528   3735    N
```

Assuming that I am the usercode 39528, there's a way to insert all the permissions that I don't know it existence? Ex: I don't know the existence of 3735,3734,3717 routines, and a want do do a insert of all possible routines for my user, may I ? I'm sorry if I couldn't explain very well, hope that you guys understand =D

ex:

```
insert into pccontro (usrcod,routcod,access) 
    values(39528,ALL POSSIBLE ROUTINES,'S');
```

Comment: Is there a  db table which lists all  100+ the  routines in question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add all missing `routcod` values and also to change the existing rows for that user so the `access` is `S` then:

```sql
MERGE INTO pccontro dst
USING (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         39528 AS usrcod,
         routcod
  FROM   pccontro
) src
ON (src.usrcod = dst.usrcod AND src.routcod = dst.routcod)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET "ACCESS" = 'S'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (usrcod, routcod, "ACCESS")
  VALUES (src.usrcod, src.routcod, 'S');
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pccontro (usrcod, routcod, "ACCESS") AS
SELECT 39528, 3717, 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 39528, 3734, 'S' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 39528, 3735, 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11111, 1000, 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12345, 2000, 'N' FROM DUAL;
```

After the merge the table contains:

> | USRCOD | ROUTCOD | ACCESS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 39528 | 3717 | S |
> | 39528 | 3734 | S |
> | 39528 | 3735 | S |
> | 11111 | 1000 | N |
> | 12345 | 2000 | N |
> | 39528 | 2000 | S |
> | 39528 | 1000 | S |

If you just want to insert the missing values and leave the existing rows with their existing values then delete the `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE` lines.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a35b1d10471c1d0f10fe8a72f881234a)*